# How to patch rsync the correct way

Tags: linux, rsync, apt

I want to patch rsync to support [detect-renamed](https://git.samba.org/?p=rsync-patches.git;a=blob;f=detect-renamed.diff;h=5ba95b4eb1b5d0f79cd22719d56fdea72590f87f;hb=HEAD) option, but I don't want to download a patch and extract it, I want to use apt (apt-get), how to do this?

Comment: This is a sourcecode patch. You have to download the rsync source code, apply the patch and build rsync yourself. You can't do this with apt.

Comment: But maybe this could help you. https://serverfault.com/a/489293/396894